# Azure VM without AzureCLI/Azure PowerShell installed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to implement a pipeline that deploys a Windows host and performs Azure-related actions through that host. The issue is that the host is deployed without Azure CLI or Azure PowerShell (Az PS) installed, and I prefer to avoid manual installations.

I have explored two different approaches:

I attempted to find a Windows image with Azure PowerShell (Az PS) or Azure CLI pre-installed, but I couldn't locate one. The only method I encountered involved manual installation followed by capturing the VM, which I aim to avoid.

I considered using extensions for installation. However, I encountered challenges such as the GUI-based installer for Azure CLI and the interactive nature of Azure PowerShell installation.

My question is: What is the correct approach for installing Azure tools on the VM? Alternatively, is there a way to execute Azure-related commands through my agent to the host, thereby bypassing the need for Azure tools on the VM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to install Azure CLI in silent mode with extension

```
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows -OutFile .\AzureCLI.msi; Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I AzureCLI.msi /quiet'; Remove-Item .\AzureCLI.msi
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to run this command after the deploy with this script:

Invoke-AzVMRunCommand `
-ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
-VMName $vmName `
-CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' `
-ScriptString <Your Snippet>

But az cli still not installed.

Comment: `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` cmdlet is used to run commands on an Azure VM, but it requires the Azure CLI to be already installed on the machine where you're running the PowerShell script, not on the VM.